# Problem with observer class not found

Tags: event-observer, magento-2.1.9

**Preconditions**

Magento 2.1.9

Php 7.0

**Steps to reproduce**

Like your documentation i have created a module for redirect user.
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/events-and-observers.html

Détail about my config file is avaible here : https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/11629

When i go to the frontend, it's show an error about the observer class does not exist :(

**Expected result**

No error

**Actual result**

```
1 exception(s):

Exception #0 (ReflectionException): Class Athena\RedirectToLanguage\Observer\AthenaObserverRedirect does not exist

Exception #0 (ReflectionException): Class Athena\RedirectToLanguage\Observer\AthenaObserverRedirect does not exist

0 /var/www/html/athenacomputing/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php(19): ReflectionClass->__construct('Athena\Redirect...')

1 /var/www/html/athenacomputing/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Definition/Runtime.php(44): Magento\Framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader->getConstructor('Athena\Redirect...')

2 /var/www/html/athenacomputing/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(71): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Definition\Runtime->getParameters('Athena\Redirect...')

3 /var/www/html/athenacomputing/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(71): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Athena\Redirect...')

4 /var/www/html/athenacomputing/vendor/magento/framework/Event/ObserverFactory.php(33): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Athena\Redirect...')

5 /var/www/html/athenacomputing/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php(59): Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverFactory->get('Athena\Redirect...')

6 /var/www/html/athenacomputing/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Manager.php(66): Magento\Framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault->dispatch(Array, Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Observer))

7 /var/www/html/athenacomputing/var/generation/Magento/Framework/Event/Manager/Proxy.php(95): Magento\Framework\Event\Manager->dispatch('controller_acti...', Array)

8 /var/www/html/athenacomputing/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(91): Magento\Framework\Event\Manager\Proxy->dispatch('controller_acti...', Array)

9 /var/www/html/athenacomputing/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
```